# I need to know which type of ANOVA to use for this problem

Tags: anova, multivariate-analysis

So I'm doing a research for this company for my thesis and I was told I should use ANOVA for this.

I have 5 dependent variables and 3 independent variables. These variables are from the same company with 3 branches. To better visualize this, here is my Operational Framework.

[image: Operational Framewokr]

Basically, I want to know the effects of the different organizational factors (shown on the left side) towards the different quality of work life factors (shown on the right side) and compare how each of the branches differ. My adviser told me to use ANOVA for the comparison parts.

Comment: "I have 5 dependent variables and 3 dependent variables"....sorry, I don't follow. Can you talk a bit more about your data, and say, null hypothesis?